# REST/stateless: CSRF attacks and remembering logged in user

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, csrf

I am using Spring-MVC and AngularJS to create my web application, but I suppose that this question can apply for any technology, since it is more of a conceptual question rather than a specific technology question.

I am struggling with understanding a few things regarding CSRF attacks as well as authenticating users on my web application. Hence, I have the following questions:

- For CSRF attacks, I read [this](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/) website which stated the following:

> Have the clients generate and send the same unique secret value in both a        Cookie and a custom HTTP header. Considering a website is only allowed to read/write a Cookie for its own domain, only the real site can send the same value in both headers. Using this approach all your server has to do is check if both values are equal, on a stateless per request basis!

Now, I don't understand what the purpose is of generating these secret values. I mean, what is the purpose of having these 2 secret values and compare them on the server? Can't an attacker just put 2 identical values inside a fake cookie and http header and still submits the form?

- From my understanding, REST is stateless, so the server does not keep track of any session on the server. In this case, I assume the user should again pass a secret value on every request to let the server now it is him? But what should the server do with this secret value? Should it be kept inside the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I don't understand what the purpose is of generating these secret values. I mean, what is the purpose of having these 2 secret values and compare them on the server? Can't an attacker just put 2 identical values inside a fake cookie and http header and still submits the form?

You are right, an attacker could add a HTTP header, but he could only set a cookie for his own domain (origin). The browser will not send a cookie to another domain:

> Considering a website is only allowed to read/write a Cookie for its own domain, only the real site can send the same value in both headers.

The server will receive only the HTTP request header from an attacker, not the cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But why would the value be important if the server only checks whether they are equal? (I assume he can add a value to the http header and cookie?)
And what if I have a web service, where e.g. a front-end application on a mobile device is communicating with my web service. I can not keep same-origin restrictions in this case right? Since this front-end is not on the same server?

Comment: ^ ah thanks for clarifying that one up.  
My apologies for my lack of understanding. Please bare with me: so now from my understanding, he receives a value from the server? (I thought this was generated by the front-end rather than server). Then this value is saved inside a cookie, which is sent back after another request to the server?

Comment: Thanks! I'm just wondering, are all browsers denying sending a cookie to another domain? What if you write your own malicious browser?

Comment: I understand, but imagine an attacker/evil guy writes an application (like a browser or something that sends a cookie from an application). Then it would still be a risk?